# Allow help in the title

Tags: bug

I tried to ask this question, but it was rejected.

> How do I install a Windows update that gives an error but no help?

The reason was retarded.

Please fix this bug.

Comment: It's not a bug it's by design.

Comment: “The reason was retarded.” - If question title includes the word help, then you have a non-descriptive title, which means you have a bad title.  So, no, not allowing the word “help” isn’t retarded.  It’s on purpose because the word help in a question title is a guaranteed sign of a bad question title.  “Please fix this bug.” - It’s not a bug but you should still choose a better title for your question.  Are you going to improve your question that caused you to ask this question?  Because you would receive a higher quality answer if you did

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110792/159016

Comment: @Chloe It’s not retarded, it’s smart, literally asking for help or a title which asks for help, is not descriptive and adds unnecessary unhelpful non-construct noise.  I reject any question that contains the word help in the title or body (in the context of asking for help)

Answer (score 6):

You could easily have changed the word help to something more descriptive.  As such the reasons not to allow it, such as titles that simply say "HELP ME!!!!" or similar, still outweigh your particular need.

For example you could have used:

- How do I install a Windows update that gives an error but no link to knowledgebase?
- How do I install a Windows update that gives an error but no more information?

And so on...

Comment: I reject this answer. I don't work for computers; computers work for me. If you want to filter 'HELP ME' then filter that title alone. This is a bug.

Comment: No, it is a feature. The word "help" was deemed unhelpful at best and in many cases actively harmful to ensuring that people provide a useful and descriptive title. There are too many variations or word groupings for filtering all of them to be worthwhile or effective. Blocking a single word is easy, blocking 50,000 variations and groupings is time consuming to set up and computationally expensive for only marginal benefit.

Comment: Also bear in mind that this site is not **your computer** and so is not "working for you", it is working **with** you. The site was written by people for people and not specifically just for you. And unless you write all of your software yourself your computer is not your own anyway and it's operation is determined by the design decisions of other people. Your computer might be doing things you want, but chances are it does a lot of things you don't want or don't care about. Your rejection of this and claiming it is a bug is irrelevant, it was an intentional design feature.

Comment: If you insist on shitty user interface than you can expect fewer users. I reject this answer. it's a bug.